# TinyMCE and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I want to add Some HTML content inside TinyMCE and display preview of that but in preview it show like that.[image][image]

I want to display content as html.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the settings for your TinyMCE installation and configure it to allow you to enter html. You need to customise the toolbar and enable 'Edit HTML Source'. A html button will then appear when you edit a page. Click that to edit the html source...

You will also find settings so the rendered page displays as html or structured text etc...